# Is there a way to capture what RecordType user has picked using apex code

Tags: apex, custom-object, class, code

I have few different record-types in my object and I like to know either by Id/Name what record-type the user have selected and based on that record type selection I have to perform some logic behind that.

I have before insert, before update trigger on `trigger.New`

```
Map<ID,RecordType> rt_Map = New Map<ID,RecordType>([Select ID, Name From RecordType Where sObjectType = 'mycustom_object__C']);

if(rt_map.get(opp.recordTypeID).name.containsIgnoreCase('YOUR VALUE')) //<<<ERROR
{
        //Do your stuff
}
```

error:

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject:
>   Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the example below 
Map rt_Map = New Map([Select ID, Name From RecordType Where sObjectType = 'Project__c']);

system.debug((rt_map.get('012g000000051uFAAQ')).name);

I am able to get the name of recordtype. In your case what is opp ? That object does not seem to be defined in your code snippet. 
Since this rt_Map is holding values for Id as Key, you must only give Id(String) to fetch values.

you can share your complete code in case it does not work.

Rgds

Comment: Is there a way to find out what record type user have selected to create a record? and I see that you are hard-coding the `id` to get the name but I was looking a way to get either its id or name based on the user selection. is that possible in apex? - the opp is a opportunity i was trying to play around ... thats psudo code

Comment: i have tried your code getting this error `unexpected token: 'Map'`

Comment: Map<ID,RecordType> rt_Map = New Map<ID,RecordType>([Select ID, Name From RecordType Where sObjectType = 'Project__c']);

system.debug((rt_map.get('012g000000051uFAAQ')).name);

Comment: Somehow the above answer did not show the map variable correctly, use as mentioned in my above comment. It is same map as you used.

Comment: I'm curious to know the question I have asked and I will repeat here again `Is there a way to find out what record type user have selected to create a record? and I see that you are hard-coding the id to get the name but I was looking a way to get either its id or name based on the user selection. is that possible in apex`

Comment: trigger insertTrigger on Case (before insert) {

for (Case cas : trigger.new) {
      System.debug(' case record Tye Id '+cas.recordTypeId);
    }

Comment: This will give you recordtype for this record which was created. I am able to get the Id field here. My initial answer was regarding snippet you pasted. Anyways, let me know in case you are still not able to get it. Once you have recordTypeId, you can use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24184/discussion-between-dave-and-abu-hamzah).